# A problem about manipulating DBRef data during anlyzing mongodb data through python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, nosql, dbref

I'm working with MongoDB and want to analyze the extracted data from this database by python to visualize required information.Two question arises: 1) in such data there is DBRef that I don't know how to manipulate it, 2) it seems that is a nested data and needs to be broken to lowe level! 3) can I covert DBref to JSON file and the analyze it?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/dbref.html).

This allows you to essentially "unpack" the DBRef and retrieve only the id's, if that is of any use to you.

Example:

```
x = {
    "oId": 567,
    "notice": [
        DBRef("noticeId", ObjectId("5f45177b93d7b757bcbd2d55"))
    ]
}
```

```
print(x.get('oId'), d.get('notice')[0].id)
```